# Understanding SVG <text> x-y coordinates and padding

Tags: html, css, svg

Fiddling with the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html,body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="1024px" height="1024px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" style="background-color: yellow">

    <text x="0" y="29"
          font-family="'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"
          font-size="32">

        Regular ol' text here. Hi.

    </text>

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect `<text>` in Chrome, it shows the height as 35.7969px. I'm not sure if this number is based on screen resolution/density or not.

Two questions:

1) What do the x and y coordinates of `<text>` represent?

2) Is there a way to remove the padding inside `<text>` so the text fits the element completely?

Comment: They are the position of the first glyph. Bottom left corner of the R in this case. What padding?

Comment: I also put this into a fiddle and didn't see any padding

Comment: When you hover over <text> when inspecting, you could see the bottom of 'g' is touching the shade, but there is whitespace above.

Comment: That's just an artifact of how the inspector works. The text could contain something taller e.g. an accented capital letter. The shading is over the whole glyph cell not the character extent.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get the height of the text itself in pixels? I believe 35.7969px is for the glyph cell?

Answer (score 7):

1. To answer the question, what does x and y refer to:

> It is the x,y coordinates of the text baseline start position (in the left bottom corner of the first char).

Open a browser that has SVG support, copy this HTML-code, read the comments:

```html
<!-- box (x,y) = 500x500 -->
<svg width="500" height="500">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500"/>

<!-- yellow text (x/2, 0) -->
<text x="250" y="0" font-family="serif" font-size="25"
 fill="yellow">Easy-peasy Easy-peasy</text>
 
<!-- green text (0, y/2)  -->
<text x="0" y="250" font-family="serif" font-size="25"
 fill="green">Easy-peasy Easy-peasy</text>
 
<!-- green line from (0, 0) to (x/2, y/2) = center-->
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="250" y2="250" stroke="green"/>

<!-- red line from (x/2, y/2) = center to left side (0, 250)  to -->
<line x1="250" y1="250" x2="0" y2="250" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 3"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: "The left hand bottom text box pixel.". No. It is the x,y coordinates of the text baseline start position. Also it does not necessarily correspond to pixels.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. But yeah, this is a more exact formulation. The code snippet provides you a good view.